# mail() isn't mailing

Tags: php, email

```
$mailHeaders = "From: webmaster@{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}\r\n" .
            "Reply-To: myemail@gmail.com\r\n" .
            "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
if (!mail($tol, $subject, $mailMessage, $mailHeaders))
{
    echo "<br />Mail failed to send. Sorry.";
}
```

It isn't echoing the `Mail failed to send. Sorry.`, so I know its sending. But I'm not receiving it in my inbox. I can't figure out why.

Aha, found a mailqueue, and found the emails there. Tried to send them again and I got this:

`retry time not reached for any host`

Can you guys close this to move to serverfault, please? :)

Comment: Yes it is. I probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: If PHP returns true, it does not mean that the mail is sent. The mailserver can still deny the mail after the mail has been received.

Comment: @Lekensteyn How do I know if that's the problem, then?

Comment: Are you using a localhost server?

Comment: No, I'm using a VPS from santrex.net

Comment: It seems to be a server problem that should be redirected to Server Fault, the server dedicated site hosted by Stack Exchange.

Comment: Hm, I agree, if no one thinks its a PHP issue. Voting to move.

Comment: @Rob, have you set up a mail server on your VPS?

Comment: @Lekensteyn, I went through the basic WHM/cPanel setup

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your spam folder?  I've run into that issue before...

Comment: Yes, been refreshing it for 20 minutes

Answer (score 0):

If its a VPS, I am guessing you have SSH access. I would try

```
tail -f /var/log/mail.*
```

To see what the box is doing with your mail.

Comment: tail: cannot open `/var/log/mail.*' for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: That's where ubuntu saves logs. Depending on your linux server, you may have to look some where else.

Answer (score 0):

Some mail servers are very tricky to manage.

**PHP Mailer** saved my life with its simple to use plugin. Takes all the complication and mystery out of PHP email. It makes HTML emails a doddle and also makes mail attachment very simple. Try it out.

I had the same problem of no emails actually being senyt. To get round my problem (which mainly lay with my server Go Daddy) I had to communicate with the SMTP Host address directly. That was the only way I could get my emails out of the Go Daddy server. So in other words almost setting up my PHP email in a similar way as you would set up an email account in Outlook. Except using my server's public SMTP gateway.

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Hope this gets you closer to your solution!

W.

Comment: I'd rather solve the problem than find a quick workaround, but thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

Dumb suggestion: preview your vars for the mail function, try `echo $tol, $subject, $mailMessage, $mailHeaders;` before the `if` condition.